# Im not able to set an initial state in my react-native application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-state

Im making a react-native app and I need to get some data (articles) from a GraphQL server and then, list the articles.

My problem is, when I run my app, the first time my HomeScreen component render, the state is empty and I cant see any of the articles because the response from the server takes some time to load.

I tried to use a condition where I check if the response has no errors and has finished loading, then I save the articles to the state son when I render my articleList, the state can have the articles, but it throws an error:
`Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

All I need is to have an initial state in my application before I render my home component

My code:

```js
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(queryRepository.GET_ARTICLES);
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  const filterByCategory = name => {
    setArticles(CategoryService.filterByCategoryName(name, data.items));
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else if (error) {
    return <Error>{error}</Error>;
  } else {
    setArticles(data.items);
  }

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <View>
        <View style={globalStyles.categoryMenuContainer}>
          <CategoryMenu filterByCategory={filterByCategory} />
        </View>
        <View style={globalStyles.reviewsContainer}>
          <ArticleList articles={articles} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: you execute `setArticles` always. just wrap it in `useEffect` and update it when `data` is changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try useEffect for set state.

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(queryRepository.GET_ARTICLES);
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  const filterByCategory = name => {
    setArticles(CategoryService.filterByCategoryName(name, data.items));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && !error && data) {
      setArticles(data.items);
    }
  }, [data, loading, error]);

  if (error) {
    return <Error>{error}</Error>;
  }
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <View>
        <View style={globalStyles.categoryMenuContainer}>
          <CategoryMenu filterByCategory={filterByCategory} />
        </View>
        <View style={globalStyles.reviewsContainer}>
          <ArticleList articles={articles} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call `setArticles`, a new render will happen in your component, hence why you should not use setters within the render function itself, you should use hook `useEffect` for that